# Install a .msi file and display the exit code of the process(.msi file)

Tags: powershell

I want to install a .msi file (it's the software winrar) and display the exit code of the process(.msi file). But I get this error:

```text
PS D:\powershell> d:\powershell\boucle.ps1
InvalidOperation: D:\powershell\boucle.ps1:20:1
Line |
  20 |  $p.WaitForExit()
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Then, I can't install the .msi file.
Is it a good method in order to install a .msi file?
Do you have a solution please?

Here is my code:

```
function executemsifile {

    param( [string]$msiFile )

    $arguments = @(
        "/i"
        "`"$msiFile`""
        "/q"
        "/l*vx"
        "log.txt"
    )
    
    $p = Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $arguments
    $p.WaitForExit()
    $p.ExitCode
    Write-Host $p.ExitCode      
}

executemsifile "D:\update4\wrar_600_64bit.msi"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `-PassThru` argument of `Start-Process`, so you don't receive output and `$p` will be `$null`.

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) noted, a possible simplification is to also use the `-Wait` switch instead of a separate `$p.WaitForExit()` call.

```
$p=Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -PassThru
$p.ExitCode
```